# Reconocer Teclas de dirección en lenguaje C con linux

Tags: c, linux

tengo una duda a ver si alguien me puede ayudar, quiero hacer un programa en C que reconozca las teclas de dirección, he visto que en windows se hace fácil con la librería windows.h y conion.h, ahora mi problema está en que quiero hacerlo en linux y pues dichas librerías no existen, así que, que alternativa se usaría para que se reconozcan las teclas de dirección en linux?

Comment: Prueba a usar [ncurses](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) :)